# Set-AzureRmKeyVaultAccessPolicy : A parameter cannot be found that matches parameter name 'PermissionsToStorage'

Tags: powershell, azure

On execute the powershell command `Set-AzureRmKeyVaultAccessPolicy -VaultName 'DssKeyVault456' -ObjectId $youruserPrincipalId -PermissionsToStorage all` I am getting the following error...

```
Set-AzureRmKeyVaultAccessPolicy : A parameter cannot be found that matches parameter name 'PermissionsToStorage'.
At line:1 char:92
+ ... KeyVault123' -ObjectId $youruserPrincipalId -PermissionsToStorage all
+                                                 ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidArgument: (:) [Set-AzureRmKeyVaultAccessPolicy], ParameterBindingException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : NamedParameterNotFound,Microsoft.Azure.Commands.KeyVault.SetAzureKeyVaultAccessPolicy
```

Any clue what could be wrong?

Comment: Are you sure that you have the most current version of the AzureRM module? If not you may want to update it and see if that resolves your issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to the error log, it seems you use a older version Azure Power Shell. The version does not support parameter `PermissionsToStorage`.

This PowerShell cmdlet will get the Azure PowerShell version.

```
Get-Module -ListAvailable -Name Azure -Refresh
```

The latest version is 5.0.1. You could download and install latest version from the [link](https://github.com/Azure/azure-powershell/releases).

Comment: I have 5.1.18362.752 version and getting the same error